# Notification alert in php mysql

Tags: php, html

I want to build a simple message system between my users of my website. For that i constructed table for messages as below:

```
tbl_messages
 -pk id int
 -fk sender_id int
 -fk receiver_id int
 -is_read boolean 
 -send_date datetime
```

When a user has my site opened in the browser and some other user sends him message, i want to send a notification message to the receiver user (something like 1 new message or (3)Messages) while the page of receiver is opened.
Eg: facebook notification, stackoverflow notification comes when new comment arrives

I performed such action by making a javascript function to be called every 2 min. This function makes an ajax request to output the notification. I wonder is this the correct and effective way to do because i have to perform the sql query every 2 min and if there are lots of records in my table, such action will create more load on database.

What other solutions can I perform instead of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly indexed your database and designed your program, it shouldn't be a problem.

You won't be able to design a notification system as responsive as Facebook and other, since it's almost impossible to create push systems with PHP.

If you have a dedicated/virtualized server (and not shared hosting), look into things such as NodeJS.

Comment: what kind of hosting do godaddy.com provide?Is it shared hosting or dedicated server?thanks for ur help

Comment: If you're asking this, it's shared.

Comment: So which columns to index if i want to go with the ajax solution.